# python 64bit から 32bit をコントロールしたい (dll が 64bit 版を参照してしまう)

Tags: python, windows

64bit Python から 32bit Python をコントロールしたいと思っています。
単純に 64bit Python でコントロールできればいいのですが、コントロールしたい機器が 32bit しかサポートしておらず、またコントローラが 64bit版しかないという状態です。

**イメージ:**
自動化ソフトウェア -- 64bit Python -- 32bit Python --> コントロールしたい機器

自動化したい機器は win32com でコントロール可能ですが 32bit のみのサポートです。32bit Python からコントロールしたい機器は制御できています。

問題は、64bit Python から 32bit Python を実行 (subprocess) しているのですが、その際 32bit Python が win32com を import するタイミングで 64bit Python の dll を参照してしまい、エラーとなっています。

**64bit からの実行**

```
import subprocess

py_path = r"C:\path\to\32bit\Python\python.exe"
cmd = r"C:\users\py\command.py"
proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [py_path, cmd],
            shell=True,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=open('out.txt', 'w'),
            stderr=open('err.txt', 'w'), 
            encoding='utf-8'
)
```

command.py

```
import win32com.client
...
```

上記を実行すると、command.py の import の時点で以下のエラーが表示され動作しません。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\users\\py\\command.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Path\to\64bit\Python\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

実際、command.py の方で sys.path を確認すると以下の通り 64bit 版を参照しに行っています。

```
['C:\\users\\py',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\32bit\\Python\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Path\\to\\64bit\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

そこで、command.py の方で sys.path.append() などを使い 32bit 版を優先的に見るようにしてみましたが、エラーに変化はありませんでした。
また、command.py で sys.path を空 ([]) にして、32bit 版のパスだけを入れてみましたが今度は win32com が見つからないとなってしまいました。

どうすればよいでしょうか?

Comment: 環境変数の`PATH`や`PYTHONPATH`で64bitPyhtonのフォルダが指定されていませんか？ それらを外したり32bitPythonのものに変更してみてはどうでしょう？ 例えばこんな記事が参考になるかも。[Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2231227/9014308)

Comment: 質問からは外れますが、[DLL Surrogates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/dll-surrogates)という技術を使うとCOM Serverを独立したプロセスで起動することができるため、結果的に32bit / 64bit問題が解消します。ただし、win32comが使えなかったところを見ると、それを行うためのレジストリ設定がされていなさそうですね…。

Comment: 読み直したら一応最後に`そこで、command.py の方で sys.path.append() などを使い ...`と対策を試したようですが、先にコメントしたように呼び出された側`command.py`で行うのではなく呼び出す側のスクリプトであらかじめ32bitPython用の専用環境変数を用意し32bit用`PATH`に変更してから呼び出してみてください。それでも`win32com が見つからない`のなら、32bitPython側に`PyWin32`がインストールされていないのでは？ ちなみに32bitコマンドプロンプト`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`を起動し上記`PATH`対策を行ってから`C:\path\to\32bit\Python\python.exe C:\users\py\command.py`を実行してみたらどのような結果になるか試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif さんのご指摘の通り、subprocess を実行する前に 32bit 用 (特にPTAHに入っていた 64bit Python の Path を削除) にして実行したところ、動作できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しましたので、自分なりの解決方法を書いておきます。

64bit Python を動かすアプリケーションでは、アプリケーション内で自動でいくつかの PATH が追加されるような動作が入っていたようで、それらの PATH を消した上で subprocess の引数 env に 32bit 用の環境変数を作って渡すことで動作することが出来ました。

```py
import os
new_env = os.environ.copy()

delete_name = ['xxx', 'yyy'] # xxx, yyy はアプリケーションの名前
add_path_list = [r'C:\path\to\32bit\python']
new_env_dict = {
    'PYTHONHOME' : r'C"\path\to\32bit\python']
}

path_list = []
for newpath in new_env ['PATH'].split(';'):
    flag = 0
    for target in delete_name:
        if target in newpath:
            flag = 1

        if flag == 0:
            path_list.append(mypath)

for newpath in add_path_list:
    path_list.append(newpath)

path_list = filter(lambda a: a != '', path_list)
path_str = ";".join(path_list)
new_env ['PATH'] = path_str

for key, value in new_env_dict.items():
     new_env[key] = value
```

として作成した new_env を subprocess の引数 env で渡します。

```py
import subprocess

py_path = r"C:\path\to\32bit\Python\python.exe"
cmd = r"C:\users\py\command.py"
proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [py_path, cmd],
            shell=True,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=open('out.txt', 'w'),
            stderr=open('err.txt', 'w'), 
            encoding='utf-8',
            env=new_env,
)
```

以上で、64bit Python から 32bit Python を動作し、32bit dll を使った動作が出来ました。

なお上記環境変数設定で、実際にはアプリケーションで使用する Python のパスだけを
削除すれば動作自体は可能でした。

ありがとうございました。